CoreWebView2WebErrorStatus is duplicated references from both EntityFrameworkCore and WinUI3
When I added the NuGet package, "EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" into my app using WinUI3, I saw the following error:-

The type 'CoreWebView2WebErrorStatus' exists in both 'Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core, Version=1.0.864.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2a8ab48044d2601e' and 'Microsoft.WinUI, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=de31ebe4ad15742b'

My development environment:

VS2022, .NET 8, WiUI3, EntityFrameworkCore

I found the following site that described the same issue as mine but I am not sure how to fix it.
https://github.com/microsoft/TemplateStudio/issues/4633
Could anyone help me to fix this issue? thank you.

for now, you should install the lower version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer that doesn't have Azure in its dependency. or if you dont want to install lower version, you can add this proeprty in your csproj <ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>false</ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>

@Katana Thank you for your comment. I tried it but the error is still there.

I also tried the lower version which is for .NET 7 but it still shows the error.

I separated the project to 2 projects that have refered to WinUI (WinAppSDK) and EntityFrameworkCore respectively. But the error still there.

Any updates on this? Running into the same problem..

@bbWebDev My solution at the moment is to downgrade the EntityFramworkCore to 6.0.31, which seems to be no error on this issue. I would really like to upgrade, but I have not yet found a solution for that.
